# How does ECS Task deployment works under the hood

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to understand how the task deployment works in ECS especially if we deploy/bounce an existing task.

I am trying to refer to best practices and using optimized strategy
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/task.html

> Choosing the correct Instance type is based on the resource
> reservation (i.e. CPU, Memory, ENI, GPU) that you configure on your
> task, hence when sizing the instance, you can calculate how many tasks
> can be placed on a single instance. A simple example of a well-placed
> task, will be hosting 4 tasks requiring 0.5 vCPU and 2GB of memory
> reservations in an m5.large instance (supporting 2 vCPU and 8 GB
> memory). The reservations of this task definition take full advantage
> of the instance’s resources.

Here is my scenario

> I have an EC2 instance with 8vcpu. I am running 2 tasks each needing 4 vcpu , so the instance is optimized for resource. Now when I deploy/bounce one of these tasks

I referred to https://www.qovery.com/blog/how-to-speed-up-amazon-ecs-container-deployments/

> Whenever a new task instance is initialized, it needs to pass a set of health checks in order to be marked as healthy and fully deployed. During this period, ECS cluster will keep running the old task instances in parallel to the newly created ones until the new ones have passed the health checks to prevent downtime. How quickly the new task instances get labeled as healthy and how fast the new task instances replace the old ones, depends on the configuration of your health checks. It also depends on how many free resources you have available on the ECS cluster.

What happens in this case - considering the new task would also require 4 vcpu, so while the task is moved from provisioning to running, I wouldn't have capacity on this instance.
Should I expect a downtime in that case? i.e. ECS will shutdown an the existing task and then move the new definition to running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this ECS uses Rolling Updates. and Rolling Updates depend on 2 parameters..

```
 1) minimumHealthyPercent
 2) maximumPercent
```

whether it will having downtime or not is depend on these 2 parameters.

The `minimumHealthyPercent` represents the lower limit on the number of tasks that should be running for a service during a deployment or when a container instance is draining, as a percent of the desired number of tasks for the service. This value is rounded up. For example if the minimum healthy percent is 50 and the desired task count is four, then the scheduler can stop two existing tasks before starting two new tasks. Likewise, if the minimum healthy percent is 75% and the desired task count is two, then the scheduler can't stop any tasks due to the resulting value also being two.

The `maximumPercent` represents the upper limit on the number of tasks that should be running for a service during a deployment or when a container instance is draining, as a percent of the desired number of tasks for a service. This value is rounded down. For example if the maximum percent is 200 and the desired task count is four then the scheduler can start four new tasks before stopping four existing tasks. Likewise, if the maximum percent is 125 and the desired task count is three, the scheduler can't start any tasks due to the resulting value also being three.